# Notepad++ Изменить нумерацию в определенных строках регулярным выражением

Tags: notepad++

Есть большие файлы, в которых определенная строка содержит нумерацию не подряд, каким образом можно поменять нумерацию с помощью регулярного выражения. найти (^0_GROUPHEADER\t)(\d+) а вот на что заменить $2, что бы нумерация бала подряд, с единицы и до последней такой строки. Может кто сталкивался с такой задачкой в NotePad++ или EmEditor

> До:

0_GROUPHEADER   6

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

0_GROUPHEADER   14

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

0_GROUPHEADER   29

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

0_GROUPHEADER   36

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

> После:

0_GROUPHEADER   1

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

0_GROUPHEADER   2

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

0_GROUPHEADER   3

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

0_GROUPHEADER   4

A1_NAME1

A2_NAME2

A3_NAME3

B1_BIRTH

Comment: этот редактор поддерживает только минимальный диалект регэкспов, в котором выполнить требуемое невозможно.  я использую редактор SciTE, там тоже регэкспы слабые, но зато требуемая обработка делается очень легко: текст в редакторе по нажатию кнопки может быть интерпретирован как Lua-программа и выполнен, так что нужно лишь дополнить содержимое одной строкой сверху (присваивание всего текста в строковую переменную) и несколькими строками снизу (обработка текста в этой переменной и печать результата), выполнить этот получившийся Lua-код и скопировать результат из output pane обратно в редактор